# Is My Chinese Name Compatible With Korean?

Tags: translation, names, sino-korean-words

I heard that many Korean names are derived from Chinese and many Koreans have a Chinese reading of their name, but can it be done vice versa?
My name is 沈丕謙, i am guessing if it translated directly, it wouldn't sound like a Korean name.
What is the literal translation of my name and how can it be altered to sound like a native name?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. A rare name though.

---

## 심<sub>沈 S(h)im</sub> 비겸<sub>丕謙 Bigyeom</sub>

An interesting question! Your characters are included in [*the legal set of hanja for personal names*](https://www.law.go.kr/LSW/lsBylInfoPLinkR.do?lsiSeq=188000) published by *the Supreme Court of South Korea*, namely “人名用漢字.” And the readings are: 심<sub>沈</sub> 비<sub>丕</sub>겸<sub>謙</sub> — romanized as “Bigyeom S(h)im.”

---

### The surname

**심<sub>沈</sub>** is the thirty-second most common surname in South Korea taking up about 0.6% of the entire population, that is more or less three hundred thousands, and the place of origin is 청송<sub>靑松 Cheongsong</sub>. It’s neither common nor uncommon.

[image: Cheongsong]

### The forename

**비겸<sub>丕謙</sub>** is possible; I wouldn’t say it sounds completely foreign. It just sounds *unique*. As of 2020, there’s only seven people with that forename, irrespective of the actual hanja, in South Korea. To make it more common, you could alter a single vowel: “비” to “보” — “심<sub>S(h)im</sub> **보**겸<sub>**Bo**gyeom</sub>.”

There are 1,338 South Koreans with the forename “보겸,” the 80% of them being male and the 20% being female, and it’s quite common, I find.

Comment: Nice answer! I wonder where did you find Korean name gender statistics?

Comment: @DanZheng It was from namechart.kr, apparently based on the official data from the Supreme Court of Korea.